# How to perform nested lookup in mongo query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is my aggregation query

```
db.user.aggregate([
  { $addFields: { user_id: { $toString: "$_id" } } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "walletData",
      let: { id: "$user_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: ["$userId", "$$id"]
                },
                {
                  $gt: ["$lastBalance", 0]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "balance"
    }
  }
])
```

I get the desired output from this result but need to join one more collection in this query. How can i achieve that?

For example consider these collections:

```
user : {
  "_id": ObjectId("xyz")
}

walletData:{
  "userId": "xyz",
  "lastBalance": 5
}


AnotherWalletdata:{
  "userId": "xyz",
  "lastBalance": 6
}
```

I got the result after joining first two tables how do i join the third table only if the balance of the second table(walletData) is greater than zero?

Expected Output :

`{"id":"xyz",
  "walletdataBal":5,
  "AnotherWalletDataBal":6
}`

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: the output should be like this - {  id:"xyz" , walletdataBal:5, anotherwalletdataBal:6}.  Now I'm getting it as {id:"xyz", walletdataBal:5, anotherwalletdata:null}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{ $unwind: "$balance" },
       { $lookup: {
           from: "walletData",
             localField: "balance.userId",
               foreignField: "userId",
                as:"anotherwalletData"
               }}
            ])`

I solved my query, I had to apply unwind after the above lookup.

Answer (score 3):

You can join any number of collections by using only `$lookup` and `$unwind` one after another followed by **Conditional Projection** for whatever that's required at last. Below is the **well-tested** and working solution for the same :

```
db.user.aggregate([
{$lookup: {from: "walletData", localField: "_id", foreignField: "userId", as: "walletDataBal"}},
{$unwind: "$walletDataBal"},
{$lookup: {from: "anotherwalletData", localField: "_id", foreignField: "userId", as: "anotherWalletDataBal"}},
{$unwind: "$anotherWalletDataBal"},
{$project: {"id": "$_id", "_id": 0, walletDataBal: "$walletDataBal.lastBalance",
anotherWalletDataBal: {$cond: 
{if: { $gt: [ "$walletDataBal.lastBalance", 0 ] },
then: "$anotherWalletDataBal.lastBalance",
else: "$$REMOVE" }}}
]).pretty();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add another [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage to achieve the output

```
db.user.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": { "user_id": { "$toString": "$_id" } } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "walletData",
    "let": { "id": "$user_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$and": [
            { "$eq": ["$userId", "$$id"] },
            { "$gt": ["$lastBalance", 0] }
          ]
        }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "balance"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "anotherWalletData",
    "let": { "id": "$user_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$and": [
            { "$eq": ["$userId", "$$id"] },
            { "$gt": ["$lastBalance", 0] }
          ]
        }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "anotherWalletData"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "walletdataBal": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$balance.lastBalance", 0] },
    "anotherwalletdataBal": {
      "$arrayElemAt": ["$anotherWalletData.lastBalance", 0]
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: thank you for the prompt response Anthony. But I tried this query earlier the problem with this query is if the balance of "walletData" user is null still it shows the balance of "Anotherwalletdata" user

Comment: Ok so do you  want to show only the balance of `anotherwalletdata` only if `walletData` balance exists? If yes then please edit your question and explain it.